# NSOutlineView Data Source not called in Mac OS 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

My app has a cell-based NSOutlineView which its data source is a NSMutableArray. In the initialisation, my app loads the NSMutableArray from a text file. Then, the NSOutlineView will be populated with the NSMutableArray.

NSOutlineView is populated with the NSMutableArray prior to OSX 10.10. In OSX 10.10, the NSOutlineView is empty, i.e. no data is displayed. I put the NSLog in the data source methods and found that in 10.10, only - (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item is called. The other 3 data source methods are not called.

I don't have OSX 10.10 to debug for this issue. Please help.

```
@interface AppController : NSObject {
    ...
    IBOutlet NSOutlineView *outlineViewCmdSet;
}

#pragma OutlineView for CmdSet
// Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? [cmdTree count] : [item numberOfChildren];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? YES : [item isExpandable];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? [cmdTree objectAtIndex:index] : [[item children] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    return [item nodeName];
}

// Delegate methods

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    return NO;
}

// Drag command to ScriptEditor
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView writeItems:(NSArray *)items toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard {
// Single Selection. items array has only 1 object
TreeItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:0];
if ([item isExpandable]) // Group Name
{
    return NO;
}
else // Command Name
{
    // Copy the Command Name to the pasteboard.
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:CommandTreeViewDataType]
                   owner:self];
    [pboard setString:[item nodeName] forType:CommandTreeViewDataType];
    return YES;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you set your delegate and dataSource, check they are not nil. Are there any warning when you compile about missing methods? Is you mutable array initialised, I.e. Not nil.

Comment: I checked the delegate via if (self == nil) and found that the delegate is not nil. The mutable array is not nil as well. What else can I check?

Comment: What about the dataSource?

Comment: From the delegate methods you have a cell-based view, make sure that view-based is not selected in your XIB.

Comment: How can you proof via `self == nil` whether the delegate is nil or not? You didn't post any code that explicitly sets the delegate, so you should prove it with `outlineViewCmdSet.delegate` (and datasource respectively).

Comment: yes, boyfarrell, I checked via if  (outlineViewCmdSet.delegate == nil) and (outlineViewCmdSet.DataSource == nil) and both are not nil.  I also ensured that the Outline View is cell-based. Hi HAS, I set the dataSource and delegate by dragging it to AppController in Interface Builder. I can't attach the screenshot here. Nonetheless, this app has been working in 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9 but 10.10.

Comment: I have confirmed that both data source and delegate are not nil as written above. I removed the connection of the Outline View to Data Source and delegate and found that outlineViewCmdSet.delegate and outlineViewCmdSet.DataSource are both nil. Any other suggestion/advice?

Comment: No other suggestions. Something has to be nil somewhere or messages are getting sent to the wrong object. Something in your project file could be corrupted? Why not start a fresh project?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I have fixed this issue by moving the initialisation of the Mutable Array from applicationDidFinishLaunching to awakeFromNib.

Strangely enough, prior to 10.10, applicationDidFinishLaunching is called before the OutlineView data source methods but not in 10.10. Anybody has any idea of this?

Comment: Your mutable array was nil, that was in my first comment! Glad you found it in the end.

Comment: Yes. Thanks boyfarrell. You are right. Strangely enough, prior to 10.10, applicationDidFinishLaunching is called before the OutlineView data source methods but not in 10.10. Anybody has any idea of this?